# HTTP Request working in postman but not with axios in docker containers

Tags: docker, http, axios

So I setup 2 containers (node and react) to talk to each other in docker.

When I try to send HTTP request using Postman everything works perfectly, but when I try with axios on client side it spits out CORS error. I have enabled cors in my node project so I don't know what's the issue. Also I should mention that GET requests work perfectly fine using axios.

Comment: can you show something related to error or minimal reproduce example?

Comment: Agree with Adiii's comment. What do you mean by you enabled CORS in your node project? What are you setting for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?